# Using layoutsubviews() works properly when cycling through UIButtons, but not when cycling while retrieving them by tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, layoutsubviews

I'm trying to mimic the iPhone Springboard drag and drop functionality for a tile game and am currently using MatrixCells to generate UIButtons in the View initalisation and add them to the view. The MatrixCells have an `order` tag, which is used for their own button as well (`[button setTag:[cell order]];`).

When using `layoutSubviews' to cycle through the UIButtons in the view to arrange them in a grid, it works fine. The grid pops up and my dragging functionality allows me to free-drag the buttons where I will.

`- (void)layoutSubviews {`

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for ( UIButton *button in [self subviews] ) {
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake( col * 80 + 5, row * 80 + 25, 70, 70)];

    if (col < 3) {
        col++;
    }
    else {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

}

However, cycling through `subviews` doesn't work when changing the order of the cells, since I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to mess around in there at all. So, I wanted to cycle through my `MatrixCells` and use their `order` to get the appropriate view and then change the `frame`. However, the layout gets messed up at button 0 and I can't use them as buttons anymore.

`- (void)layoutSubviews {`

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (MatrixCell *cell in currentOrder) {
    UIView *view = [self viewWithTag:[cell order]];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake( col * 80 + 5, row * 80 + 25, 70, 70 )];
    if (col < 3) {
        col++;
    }
    else {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Here is a picture with the results: http://i52.tinypic.com/2q903lk.png

`viewWithTag` seemed the be the most elegant solution for this. So I'm at a loss. Any idea why these implementations don't render the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self viewWithTag:0]` returns `self` first, instead of the expected `(UIButton *)`, since I didn't change the view's `tag` upon initialization. Apparantly tags default to 0 at initialization. `layoutsubviews` then proceeded to change the `frame` of `self`, messing up the layout and functionality. I solved this dilemma by changing the view's tag to 999 at initialization.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me rather like you have a background `UIImage` to provide that grey gradient backdrop. It also looks like your button `0` might have a `[cell order]` of 0. I'm going to guess that you've never changed the tag of your background `UIImage`, which will thus default to 0.

When you call `[self viewWithTag]` for the first `UIButton` (labeled 0), it will find the first subview with a tag 0 - the background image, not the `UIButton` you expected - and move that. This, I suspect. is why all the other buttons line up fine, why the background moves oddly, and why your 0 button is not visible.

Comment: Not completely correct, but it brought me on the right track. I just set a `UIColor` for the background and the buttons just have a `setImage` as well. However, `[self viewWithTag:0]` returned `self`, of course completely messing up its frame, forgetting about button 0 and not allowing me to access the other buttons (since the frame didn't reach that far). But I solved it, so thanks! What's the protocol now, do I mark this answer as the correct one? Or should I answer my own question instead?

Comment: Ah, my psychic debugging failed (but only just!). In this case, I'd probably write my own answer, and accept that. But an upvote never goes amiss ;)

Comment: Alas, I'm still a lowly student without even enough reputation to vote. But when that becomes possible, I'll make sure to do so :)